# How do i check a radio button is checked or not using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4

How do i check a radio button is checked or not using jquery???

here is the code:

```
     function handlesClick(myRadio) {
        debugger
       var selectedmerchant = [];
        if (myRadio != '') {
            var myRadios = $('input[name=myRadio]');
            //var checkedValue = $("#myRadio").attr('checked', 'checked');
            //if ($('#myRadio').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
            //$('input[type="radio"][class="icheck-list"]:checked').val()
            if ($("#myRadio").is(":checked") === true)
            {
                selectedmerchant.push(myradio);
                selectedmerchant.join(",");
            }
            else
            {
 var index = selectedmerchant.indexof(merchant);
               selectedmerchant.splice(index, 1);
            }
     //if (document.getelementbyid(myradio).checked == true) {
            //    selectedmerchant.push(myradio);
            //    selectedmerchant.join(",");
            //}
            //else {
            //    var index = selectedmerchant.indexof(merchant);
            //    selectedmerchant.splice(index, 1);
            //}
```

i want to check is the checkbox is checked or not so that i can push or slice in a array using javascript.
any code???

here is the html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>3.sdfdsfsdfds</label>
        <div class="icheck-list">
          <label class="icheck-list" id="11">

            <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_11" type="radio">Strongly Disagree
            <span></span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="icheck-list">
          <label class="icheck-list" id="12">
            <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_12" type="radio">Disagree
            <span></span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="icheck-list">
          <label class="icheck-list" id="13">
            <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_13" type="radio">Neither Agree or Disagree
            <span></span>
          </label>     
        </div>
        <div class="icheck-list">
          <label class="icheck-list" id="14">
            <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_14" type="radio">Agree
            <span></span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="icheck-list">
          <label class="icheck-list" id="15">
            <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_15" type="radio">Strongly Agree
            <span></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: not working thats why i am asking man

Comment: show some relevant html

Comment: That probably means your code is not called correctly

Comment: i have edited in html..

Comment: can anyone tell me any code??

Comment: @Swapper look my html

Comment: Format you html and js )

Comment: what i am not getting???

Comment: is there any wrong with html or anythings??

Comment: I feel here is issue, var myRadios = $('input[name=myRadio]');
    if ($("#myRadio").is(":checked") === true) {

Comment: @Swapper not working

Comment: nothing comes error or nothing happen

Comment: itis not going to if or else conditions

Comment: `handlesClick` doesn't have a `}` infact the function you've posted is totally invalid as the if is also missing a `}`. Create an proper example of your problem then people can help. Dumping junk code into a question and saying why doesn't this work isn't productive for anyone.

Comment: thats my mistake while posting but that is not a issue on my code.

Comment: any one provide me a proper answer??

Comment: `$("#myRadio")` doesn't exist. You probably meant `$(myRadio)`. You should work on refactoring your code; it's such a tangled rats-nest, it's no wonder you're making simple mistakes like this.

Comment: there is 10 questions so at the end i need 10 array element...if suppose i click Strongly Disagree and after sometime click Agree then both the array stores in selectedmerchant ,so i need to replace or delete first array what i store.okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this,

```js
window.selectedmerchant = {};
function handlesClick(myRadio) {
  if ($(myRadio).is(":checked")) {
   window.selectedmerchant[$(myRadio).attr("name")] = $(myRadio).attr("id");
  }
  console.log(window.selectedmerchant);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>3.sdfdsfsdfds
      </label>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="11">
          <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_11" type="radio">Strongly Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="12">
          <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_12" type="radio">Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="13">
          <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_13" type="radio">Neither Agree or Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="14">
          <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_14" type="radio">Agree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="15">
          <input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_15" type="radio">Strongly Agree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>4. fourth question
      </label>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="13">
          <input name="4" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="4_13" type="radio">Strongly Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="14">
          <input name="4" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="4_14" type="radio">Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="15">
          <input name="4" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="4_15" type="radio">Neither Agree or Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="16">
          <input name="4" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="4_16" type="radio">Agree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="17">
          <input name="4" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="4_17" type="radio">Strongly Agree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label>5.5th question
      </label>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="18">
          <input name="5" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="5_18" type="radio">Strongly Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="19">
          <input name="5" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="5_19" type="radio">Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="20">
          <input name="5" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="5_20" type="radio">Neither Agree or Disagree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="21">
          <input name="5" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="5_21" type="radio">Agree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="icheck-list">
        <label class="icheck-list" id="22">
          <input name="5" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="5_22" type="radio">Strongly Agree
          <span></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
```

I have taken only three examples just as demo, but check the code, its working fine now.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

For this please try below code :

```
<input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_1" type="radio">Agree

<input name="3" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="3_2" type="radio">Disagree
```

// Here is the JS code //

```
function handlesClick(RadioId) {

if (RadioId != '') {
if ($(RadioId).is(":checked") === true) 
    {

  //Add condition for checked Radio

     } 
 else 
    {

   //Add condition for unchecked Radio

    }
  }
}
```